# process is not defined when Deploying Quasar project to Netlify

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, vuejs3, netlify, quasar-framework

I have a `.env` file and I use `dotenv` package to manage that file and supply it to Quasar in `quasar.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
    // ...
    build: {
     // ...
      env: {
        ...require('dotenv').config().parsed
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

From my experience, I know that on Netlify I get the issue because the `.env` file doesn't exist on the server when the build command runs in the folder `dist/spa`.

I tried adding environment variables there via their UI but still, the error is there even after re-deploying by clearing cache.

It's my first time deploying on Netlify and I thought it would be easy but I don't know how to solve the environment variables issue.

---

I have deployed to Github pages and on other servers using Github actions, and the way I did it was:

- Add GitHub secrets with the content of `.env`
- Creating a `.env` file on the fly:

```sh
      - name: Create env
        env:
          ENV: ${{ secrets.ENV }}
        run: echo "$ENV" > ./.env
```

That works great, but for my project, I wanted to try Netlify because it's easy and we don't need GitHub actions to enable automatic deployment. Plus it has some extra features that I like.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but I solved it by updating the `quasar.config.js` and actually re-defining all my environment variables:

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  require('dotenv').config() 

  return {
    // ...
    build: {
     // ...
      env: {
        API: process.env.API, 
        ANOTHER_KEY: process.env.ANOTHER_KEY
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Credits: accepted answer on Quasar Discussions](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/12061#discussioncomment-1978284)